# Get Rectangle's color after FillRectangles

Tags: c#, .net, rectangles, getcolor

How can I get the color of a `Rectangle` after creating it?

I'm using this code to create them :

```
SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
Rectangle[] rects = { new Rectangle(0, 0, 15, 15), new Rectangle(16, 16, 15, 15), new Rectangle(16, 0, 15, 15), new Rectangle(0, 16, 15, 15) };
g.FillRectangles(sb,rects);
```

And now I want to get the color of the 3rd rectangle
`rects[2] =` ....

Is it possible to get this? And it should return `Color.Red`.

Comment: you want to get or set?

Comment: i want to get  only

Comment: _panel1.CreateGraphics();_ Never do this!! - Winforms graphics basic rule #1 : 

Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter.. - If you do it right you will be able to find out about colors, either from the bitmap or via drawtobitmap; the way you do it now it will not work..

Comment: @TaW probably 'copied' from [How to: Draw a Filled Rectangle on a Windows Form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-draw-a-filled-rectangle-on-a-windows-form)

Comment: @J.vanLangen haha exacly :D

Comment: @adam I would rather refer you to this example: [How to: Create a Bitmap at Run Time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-a-bitmap-at-run-time) but do not recreate the bitmap everytime, just create it ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store the image, you only store the result (i.e. the grid of pixels). There is no information on **how you created** this image.

E.g. based on the bitmap image alone, you cannot differentiate between two adjacent squares (`new Rectangle(0, 0, 15, 15), new Rectangle(15, 0, 15, 15)` and a single rectangle that has twice the width (`new Rectangle(0, 0, 30, 15)`).

So the short answer to your question is no, you cannot do that.

Unless you store your information (the rectangles you drew) separately and then use that to find the appropriate pixel on the image (and this only works in simple cases - if you overlapped an earlier rectangle, it's going to be impossible)

But if you're going to store the rectangle information anyway, you might as well store its color and then you don't need to reverse engineer the image anymore. So the answer remains that **you cannot do this based on an image alone**.

Comment: Thank you for explain. I can just save color to 2D dimension just and later overrwrite this dimension + redraw rectangle. That's the answer how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the position of center pixel of your rectangle, then you can use `GetPixel` method to get information about such as color.

```
   Color pixelColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(50, 50);
```

Comment: What about overdraw?

Comment: @adam: If you store the image, you only store the result (i.e. the grid of pixels). There is no information on _how you created_ this image. E.g. based on the bitmap image alone, you cannot differentiate between two adjacent squares and a single rectangle that has twice the width. So the short answer to your question is no, you cannot do that. Unless you store your information (the rectangles you drew) separately and then use that to find the appropriate pixel on the image (and this only works in simple cases - if you overlapped an earlier rectangle, it's going to be impossible)

Comment: @adam: Note that if you're going to store the rectangle information anyway, you might as well store its color and then you don't need to reverse engineer the image anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The FillRectangles draws the rectangles with the brush (color) you passed. There is no reference from any rectangle to any color. It just executes a drawing command to a `Graphics` object.

**A Rectangle doesn't have a color.** So, nope, you cannot. If you explain why you would need it, there might be other solutions to get the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a new Class, for example:

```
class ColorRectangles
{
    public Color color;
    public Rectangle[] rects;

    public ColorRectangle(Rectangle[] rects, Color color) : base(x, y, width, height)
    {
        this.color = color
        this.rects = rects;
    }
}
```

and then set the Rectangles Color with `g.FillRectangles(new SolidBrush(Rectangle.color), Rectangle.rects);`

Comment: `rects` is an array of rectangles.